# Building Boost_1_55_0's example asynchronous TCP daytime server

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp

I'm trying to build Boost's example of an asynchronous TCP daytime server found on this link:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3/src.html

Here what I am trying to build the example with:

```
g++ -o server server.cpp -I ~/boost/include -L~/boost/lib -lboost_system
```

Here are the errors I am getting:

```
 g++ -o server server.cpp -I ~/boost/include -L~/boost/lib -lboost_system
/tmp/ccF38gvh.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
server.cpp:(.text+0x221): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
server.cpp:(.text+0x22d): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
server.cpp:(.text+0x239): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccF38gvh.o: In function `boost::system::error_code::error_code()':
server.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6system10error_codeC2Ev[_ZN5boost6system10error_codeC5Ev]+0x17): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccF38gvh.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
server.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv[boost::asio::error::get_system_category()]+0x5): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

What do I need to add to get this to successfully build?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally hit enter and sent this out before I was finished

Comment: That's a browser bug, if "Enter" submits the post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your command line is different.

In particular, could it be you have the source listed /after/ the libs?

Specificly

```
g++ -o server -I "$HOME/boost/include" -L"$HOME/boost/lib" -lboost_system server.cpp
```

would **not** work, and

```
g++ -o server server.cpp -I "$HOME/boost/include" -L"$HOME/boost/lib" -lboost_system
```

should work.

Other than that, see also [c++ files to include for boost : asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460164/c-files-to-include-for-boost-asio/22463998#22463998). The jam-file for the tutorials build everything with `-lboost_system -lboost_thread -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1` (which is likely overkill)

**Update** Also found this [How to compile boost async_client.cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312653/how-to-compile-boost-async-client-cpp/22313790#22313790)

Comment: I moved the position of "server.cpp" and it still isn't working. I will look at the link you have provided. Thanks

Comment: I have tried using: g++ -o server -I ~/boost/include -L~/boost/lib -lboost_system -lboost_thread -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 server.cpp              And I have gotten a different error now: /usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.53.0, needed by /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so, may conflict with libboost_system.so.5

Comment: That's **not** an error. Just make sure your LD_LIBRARY_PATH finds the required version at runtime. You can also look at the `-Wl,rpath` option. (The linker is warning you that your system LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains a conflicting verion of the same library)

Comment: so I can use the (-Wl, rpath) option to specify which version I want?

Comment: You can use it to avoid having to override the LD_LIBRARY_PATH manually. Of course, baking it into the binary is somewhat limited (especially since if it refers to a machine specific path). Just giving you the options

Comment: I just found another old answer that shows the `-Wl,-rpath` approach (something tells me SO search is not that useless after all)